# Unable to upload Nativescript images to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a nativescript-vue application where I want to take a camera taken image and upload to my S3 bucket.

I installed the plugin:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-aws-sdk
```

I have in my app.js:

```
import { S3 } from "nativescript-aws-sdk/s3";  
S3.init({ endPoint: '/images/person', accessKey: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretKey: config.AWS_SECRET_KEY, type: 'static' });
Vue.use(S3);
```

then in my function to upload an image:

```
uploadPicture() {

console.log('uploadPicture called..');
const s = new S3();
console.log('S3 inited..' + JSON.stringify(s));
```

But this results in:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/@nativescript/core/image-source/image-source.js:331:16: 'fromNativeSource() is deprecated. Use ImageSource constructor instead.'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/components/Photo.vue:303:0: 'uploadPicture called..'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/components/Photo.vue:304:0: 'S3 const..undefined'
```

So there is something with the S3.init() that is causing an error.  I do not see many examples of this plugin online so either nobody has issues with it or its not being used?

Anyone who can see what I am doing wrong, can you kindly point me in the right direction?

**Update**:
Moved the import from vue file to app.js:

```
 import { S3 } from "nativescript-aws-sdk/s3";  
 S3.init({ endPoint: '/images/person', accessKey: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretKey: config.AWS_SECRET_KEY, type: 'static' });
```

And in my Vue file:

```
import { S3 } from 'nativescript-aws-sdk/s3';
const s3 = new S3();



const imageUploaderId = s3.createUpload({
      file: that.cameraImage,
      bucketName: config.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      key: `ns_${isIOS ? 'ios' : 'android'}`+fileName,
      acl: 'public-read',
      completed: (error, success) => {
         if (error) {
            console.log(`S3 Download Failed :-> ${error.message}`);
         }
         if (success) {
            console.log(`S3 Download Complete :-> ${success.path}`);
         }
      },
      progress: progress => {
         console.log(`Progress : ${progress.value}`);
      }
      }).catch((err) => {
          console.error("createUpload() caught error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
      });

s3.pause(imageUploaderId);
s3.resume(imageUploaderId);
s3.cancel(imageUploaderId);
```

But nothing seems to happen - no errors or progress.

Comment: Which platform you have issues with, iOS / Android?

Comment: I am testing with iOS at the moment but eventually it should support both.

Comment: You're not following the instructions? https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-aws-sdk

Comment: Yes, My code looks right but the S3.init is stopping execution.  The only way I could get it to build was to change the import to:   const S3 = require(' nativescript-aws-sdk/s3').S3;

Comment: No it's not  the same. Note it says to `S3.Init`  *// <= Try calling this before the app start*. The difference is that you've declared `const S3 = require...` but their declaration of `S3` is from the import.

Comment: I tried the plugin on my end, it seems to work. If you still have issues, please share a sample project.

Comment: I see that I need to have the import {S3} and S3.init in my app.js.  But in the directions the vue file makes use of a "s3" without importing or referencing that anywhere.  There is a disconnect somewhere between the two lines in my app.js and my line to unresolved variable "s3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared S3 twice, once globally:

```
import S3 from "nativescript-aws-sdk/s3";
```

and I'm guessing a local version inside the uploadPicture() method:

```
const S3 = require('nativescript-aws-sdk/s3').S3;
```

The import S3 has to do the init, not the later as per: https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-aws-sdk

Comment: I updated with my changes - moving the import to app.js.  However, I cannot startup if I have 'S3.S3.init(' only with 'S3.init('. But how do I use the S3 in my vue file ?