# nativescript & S3

Tags: amazon-s3, nativescript

Part 2 of a [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877651/unable-to-upload-nativescript-images-to-s3) on uploading camera images from my iOS to my S3 account
I have an S3 bucket with the default ACL and policy.  I finally got my [nativescript-aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-aws-sdk/v/0.0.4) to build and but I am struggling to see what I need to do to actually use it..

I have this:
**app.js**:

```
import { S3 } from "nativescript-aws-sdk/s3";
S3.init({ endPoint: '/images/person', accessKey: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretKey: config.AWS_SECRET_KEY, type: 'static' });
```

**person.vue:**

```
<script>
    import { takePicture, requestPermissions } from "nativescript-camera";
    import config from "../../config.json";
    import { S3 } from 'nativescript-aws-sdk/s3';
    const s3 = new S3();
    ...
    requestPermissions()
       .then( () => {
           takePicture({ width: that.width, height: that.height, keepAspectRatio: that.keepAspectRatio, saveToGallery: that.saveToGallery, allowsEditing: that.allowsEditing })
       .then((imageAsset) => {
          that.cameraImage = imageAsset;
          ...
       }

    uploadPicture() {
         console.log('uploadPicture called..');
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var timestamp = currentDate.getTime();
            let fileName = this.person.lastName+ timestamp + '.jpg';
            console.log('working with image file: ' + fileName);
            console.log('working with image : ' + that.cameraImage);
            const imageUploaderId = s3.createUpload({
                file: that.cameraImage,
                bucketName: config.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
                key: `ns_${isIOS ? 'ios' : 'android'}`+fileName,
                acl: 'public-read',
                completed: (error, success) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(`S3 Download Failed :-> ${error.message}`);
                    }
                    if (success) {
                        console.log(`S3 Download Complete :-> ${success.path}`);
                    }
                },
                progress: progress => {
                    console.log(`Progress : ${progress.value}`);
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error("createUpload() caught error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            });

            console.log('working with iimageUploaderId: ' + imageUploaderId);
            // s3.pause(imageUploaderId);
           // s3.resume(imageUploaderId);
            // s3.cancel(imageUploaderId);
        }
```

However, I feel like I must be doing something wrong because the createUpload doesn't seem to complete as my error logs are:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/components/Person.vue:304:0: 'uploadPicture called..'
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/components/Person.vue:308:0: 'working with image file: Flintstone1585334134497.jpg'
```

So am I missing something?

Comment: What is cameraImage?

Comment: That is the image from the camera (which I display):   takePicture(...).then((imageAsset) => { that.cameraImage = imageAsset;...}

Comment: iOS do not return actual file, it has something called PHAsset within ImageAsset. You will have to write the asset to your local folder and send the path to plugin.

Comment: thank you, I will look into how to create a file from that ImageAsset.  Does the rest of the call look right - the actual uploading of a file?